# Where can I find a list of all the badges for Arqade?

Tags: support, badges

I used the search for 10 minutes but came up with nothing. =(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tab on the front page called [badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges) that links to the list of all of the badges:
[image]